# How to add static HTML inside generated template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to add static HTML inside generated template?

I have that code:

```
<test></test>
<test></test>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        template:
        '<div class="wrapper">' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    };
});
</script>
```

... And then, I want to add `<p>foo</p>` (see yellow note below) inside first `<content>`, but not inside second. So, the output should be:

```
<test>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            foo
        </div>
    </div>
</test>

<test>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</test>
```

How I can do it?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12gq1rc7/1/) as aksed in the comments.

> Note: This is just SO example. In the real code, it should be added more complex HTML markup, not simple `<p>foo</p>`. For example, it may be added something like: `<div class="..."><p>...</p><p>...</p></div>`. Or, maybe, some HTML table. That is what I want.

Comment: You want to add how? Programmatically, at what moment?

Comment: You could for example put a flag or something on the place the text belongs. Then get the template and replace the flag

Comment: Can you  make fiddle for it?

Comment: @HassanTariq Fiddle added. Also, please see yellow note at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: @WouterdenOuden Very interesting, thanks.

Comment: Can't you use `transclude` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) here.

You would define your directive like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template:
        `<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
            </div>
        </div>`
    };
});
```

Then in your HTML, you would have:

```
<test>
    <p>foo</p>
</test>
<test></test>
```

And the `<p>foo</p>` will be inserted automatically inside the `ng-transclude` element in your template.

More information on [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive("test", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var childContent = '';
            if(attrs.content == 'foo')
                childContent = '<p>foo</p>';

            var htmlText = '<div class="wrapper">' +
                '<div class="content">' +
                childContent+
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            element.append($compile(htmlText)(scope));
        }
    };
});
```

**Template**

```
<test content='foo'></test>
<test></test>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Assuming you already know what content to add for each directive.

```
<test content="foo"></test>
<test content=""></test>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("test", function() {
    return {
       template: function(el, attrs){
        '<div class="wrapper">' +
        '<div class="content">' + '<p>'+attrs.content+'</p>'
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
       }
    };
});
</script>
```

That would give you the desired output.

Comment: In your code the `<p>` element is added even if there is no content.