# Insert one template into another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to insert one template into another?

> Note: This question is an extension of this one: [How to add static HTML inside generated template in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865975)

I have an angular directive which will insert `<div class="wrapper">...</div>` (colored red in the image below) inside the left column of the table, and `<p>bar</p>` inside the right column.

The graphic output:

[image]

Here is [the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYhqbeytyBzdiV338m0m?p=preview).

Here are the files:

**test.html**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <sides>
        <side-left>
            <div class="wrapper"><div class="content"><p>foo</p></div></div>
        </side-left>
        <side-right>
            <p>bar</p>
        </side-right>
    </sides>

</body>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('sides', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: {
            'left': 'sideLeft',
            'right': 'sideRight'
        },

        /* The 1st template */
        template:
        `<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="50%">
                    <div ng-transclude="left"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <div ng-transclude="right"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>`

    };
})

})(window.angular);
```

**app.css**

```
table {width: 100%}
table, tr, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}
.wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(245,205,205);
}
```

This works fine. But now, I want to change how it works.

The `<div class="wrapper">` and `<div class="content">` should be generated from another template, and then be inserted into the first template (which is shown slightly above).

With that change, I can get the same resulting HTML and visual result (as shown at the picture above) with writing something like:

**test.html**

```
    <!-- ... -->

    <sides>
        <side-left>
            <wrapper>
                <p>foo</p>
            </wrapper>
        </side-left>
        <side-right>
            <p>bar</p>
        </side-right>
    </sides>

    <!-- ... -->
```

How could this be done?

Comment: That's where I would write my own directive.

Comment: @JohannesJander Thanks :-)

Comment: Also take a look at [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to dynamically include templates

Comment: @Aides Thank you very much too :-) Now it's a 300-bounty question :-)

Comment: What exactly do you want for an answer?

Comment: @JohannesJander I tried to resolve the problem myselft, but with no luck. I'm just a novice at Angular. Now this question is 300-bounty, so may be you can have a time to look it again :-)

Comment: @Aides The working example :-) If I need to provide some additional details of the problem, we may describe them somewhere.

Comment: wanna join me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/106047/angular-question-on-template-injection?

Comment: @johnc.j. Checkout my answer below. And let me know if you were looking for this or something similar. Thanks.

Comment: @johnc.j. I have set up a solution for you, please check it out.

Comment: @johnc.j. Would you mind having a look at my answer?

Comment: @DivakarDass I looked and leaved comments. I just need a time to read the code and test. And also, the time for writing comments, which will be enough easy to understand (because I'm not native english speaker) :-)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer and awarding the bounty. I feel a bit bad to take away most of your reputation points now...

Comment: That's not a problem at all! The question was really important for me, so it's a good thing to set a bounty. Also, your answer provided some useful tricks. I'm going to use this technique for writing large complex HTML documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your use-case (don't take it the wrong way, I am not an English native speaker, but I have the impression your description could be clearer).

However I believe all you need is another directive.

I have put together a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/degamehali/1/edit?html,js,output) that shows how it all fits together. Here are the relevant parts:

**Directive `wrapper`**

```
.directive('wrapper', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,

        /* The 2nd template */
        templateUrl:
        '/tpl-wrapper.html'

    };
})
```

**Template for `wrapper`**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
       <div ng-transclude />
   </div>
</div>
```

**Main HTML**

```
<sides>
    <side-left>
        <wrapper>
            <p>foo</p> 
        </wrapper>
    </side-left>
    <side-right>
        <p>bar</p>
    </side-right>
</sides>
```

A couple of notes:

1. I have separated the directive HTML out into [script-templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) because that makes the Javascript part more concise and easier to read. You can of course copy them back in and change `templateUrl` to `template`.
2. The `wrapper` directive does the same as your `sides` directive, but needs only one slot for transclusion. Whatever you write inside gets copied back into the resulting HTML
3. Your resulting HTML still contains tags like `<sides>` or `<side-left>`. I don't know if that is desired (it's allowed in HTML5 after all), but I would try to move them to `<div class="sides">` and `<div class="side-left">`

If you want to fix the last point then you can use the `link`-function to replace the unusual tags:

```
link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
     el.replaceWith(el.children());
}
```

I have prepared [a second version of my JSBin](https://jsbin.com/coruhajaka/1/edit?html,js,output) that shows this for `<sides>` and `<wrapper>` (and also uses Angular 1.5, so the multi-slot transclusion works).

Comment: The image is a bit different because multi-slot transclusion is available since Angular 1.5.0 (your JSBin is currently using 1.4.0). So, that's not a problem :-)

Comment: Oh, you are right, well if you switch it to 1.5.0, it works :)